# If input value is not a number it should be skipped in c#

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, do-while

I'm tying to write a code where continuous input of numbers from the keyboard until the user enters 0.
After that, the program should display count of previously inputted numbers.

rules is:

- Get all input values from Console
- If input value is not a number it should be skipped
- Use only while or do-while loops

my code works for numbers but if my input is letter it's acts like input 0, stops working
I'm trying to ignor letters and continue untill input is 0

this is my code:

```
using System;

namespace practice_01
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //global variable
        int numberFromInput;
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            //input form user
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter number: ");
            var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            //check if input is number
            var isNumber = int.TryParse(userInput, out numberFromInput);
            count++;

            //if it's letter just skip
            if (!isNumber)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // input 0 is not part of count
            if(numberFromInput == 0)
            {
                count = count - 1;
            }
        } 
        while (numberFromInput != 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"Count of entered numbers before zero: {count}");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're incrementing the counter before doing the continue, so even if you entered a letter it will count as a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you're incrementing the `count` as soon as you get an input, so it will be incremented even for a letter.
Second, your condition checks if `numberFromInput` is `0`, so even when `TryParse()` fails, that value is still `0` so you exit the loop.

This will fix both:

```
bool isNumber = true;
do
{
    //input form user
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter number: ");
    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    //check if input is number
    isNumber = int.TryParse(userInput, out numberFromInput);

    //if it's letter just skip
    if (!isNumber)
    {
        isNumber = true;
        continue;
    }

    // input 0 is not part of count
    if (numberFromInput == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    count++;
}
while (isNumber);
```

Note that, in case the `isNumber` is `false`, we set it back to `true` before doing the `continue` in order to stay in the loop. And finally, having `count++` *after* the `break` in case input is zero eliminates the need to adjust the counter and simply lets you break out of the loop.

Comment: Move  count++; to the line before the }while; and remove if(numberFromInput == 0)

Comment: I got this one, if I input letter program outputs count correctly , what I'm trying to do is just ignor or skipp letters, continue loop untill input is 0

Comment: You need to also change the condition. Let me fix the code.

Comment: @levanijincharadze Continuious Input loops in console until the user starts making sense are simple. This do...while is basically made for it. You could either use the return alue of tryParse directly, or store it in bool to use for other stuff instead. As a advanced thematic, you may want to have a way to cancel the whole input process in case the user re-decided.

Comment: Oh, I see now what was problem